# How do we reach at the formula for UCB action-selection in multi-armed bandit problem?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multi-armed-bandits, upper-confidence-bound

I came across the formula for Upper Confidence Bound Action Selection (while studying multi-armed bandit problem), which looks like:

$$
A_t \dot{=} \operatorname{argmax}_a \left[ Q_t(a) + c \sqrt{ \frac{\ln t}{N_t(a)} } \right]
$$

Although, I understand what the second term in the summation actually means but I am not able to figure out how and from where the exact expression came from, what is the log doing there? What effect does $c$ have? And, why a square root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an intuitive description/explanation.

$c$ is there for a trade-off between exploration and exploitation. If $c=0$ then you only consider $Q_t(a)$ (no exploration). If $c \rightarrow \infty$ then you only consider exploration term.
$\frac{\ln t}{N_t(a)}$ is there to balance out exploration term. If you consider a simple case where you only have one action (then it wouldn't make sense to explore you could always pick that action but let's pretend there is) then as $t \rightarrow \infty$, because $\ln t$ has sublinear growth,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\ln t}{N_t} \rightarrow 0
\end{equation}
So, after you picked an action infinitely many times, the exploration term will completely diminish, i.e. you already know a lot about what that action does. If you picked a numerator that doesn't have sublinear growth, then as $t \rightarrow \infty$ exploration term would not diminish, so you would always have a chance to explore and exploration term can "overpower" action value term if $Q_t$ is very small, even after you picked an action infinitely many times, which is not desired.

A similar thing is with multiple actions, $\ln t$ will make sure the exploration term $\rightarrow 0$ if you picked it many times, but it's still better than constant term $K/N_t(a)$, where $K$ is some constant, because it can diminish too fast.

With $\ln t$ you will also not stop exploring completely if you haven't picked some action in a long time, because $\ln t$ will keep growing and $N_t(a)$ will remain the same, so their fraction will increase with time, which is useful in non-stationary environments.

The *square root* is also there probably to balance out the magnitude of exploration term.

You can also see this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323867/upper-confidence-bound-in-machine-learning). It has couple of links to some papers for a more mathematical description.