# Why do we have two similar action selection strategies for UCB1?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policies, sutton-barto, multi-armed-bandits, upper-confidence-bound

In the literature, there are at least two action selection strategies associated with the UCB1's action selection strategy/policy. For example, in the paper [Algorithms for the multi-armed bandit problem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.6028.pdf) (2000/2014), at time step $t$, an action is selected using the following formula

$$
a^*(t) \doteq \arg \max _{i=1 \ldots k}\left(\hat{\mu}_{i}+\sqrt{\frac{2 \ln t}{n_{i}}}\right) \tag{1}\label{1},
$$
where

- $\hat{\mu}_{i}$ is an estimate of the expected return for arm $i$
- $n_i$ is the number of times the action $i$ is selected
- $k$ is the number of arms/actions

On the other hand, [Sutton & Barto](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf#page=57) (2nd edition of the book) provide a slightly different formula (equation 2.10)

$$
a^*(t) \doteq \arg \max _{i=1 \ldots k}\left(\hat{\mu}_{i}+c\sqrt{\frac{\ln t}{n_{i}}}\right) \tag{2}\label{2},
$$
where $c > 0$ is a hyper-parameter that controls the amount of exploration (as explained in the book or [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/20170/2444)).

Why do we have these two formulas? I suppose that both are "upper confidence bounds" (and, in both cases, they are constants, though one is a hyper-parameter), but why (and when) would we use one over the other? They are not equivalent because $c$ only needs to be greater than $0$, i.e. it can be arbitrarily large (although, in the mentioned book, the authors use $c=2$ in one experiment/figure). If $c = \sqrt{2}$, then they are the same.

The answer to my question can probably be found in [the original paper that introduced UCB1](https://homes.di.unimi.it/cesa-bianchi/Pubblicazioni/ml-02.pdf) (which actually defines the UCB1 as in \ref{1}),  or in a paper that derives the bound, in the sense that the bound probably depends on some probability of error, but I have not fully read it yet, so, if you know the answer, feel free to derive both bounds and relate the two formulas.

Answer (score 2):

In the PDF of the original paper for UCB1 you linked, in page 242-243 the authors proves why non-optimal machines get played much less (in fact, logarithmically less) than the optimal ones. $c$ decides whether they indeed would, and $c=\sqrt{2}$ is the minimum choice of $c$.

We want to show that the number of runs for non-optimal machines ($n_i$, for non-optimal $i$s, in your notation) is asymptotically logarithmic. In other words, you may run them for a few times and well, it's fine, but not too often. We're devising some indicator value $a_i(t)=\hat \mu_i+(\epsilon...)$ such that the *mistaken* cases, where values of non-optimal ones surpass values of optimal ones ($a^*(t)<a_i(t)$), are minimized.

Think about the last inequality. We know that $\mu^* > \mu_i$ (again, optimal and non-optimal ones). Therefore, for that inequality to be true, it seems either the left-hand side should be *quite* small or the right-hand side should be *quite* large. But wait, $\hat \mu$s are actually some random trials for $\mu$, so we cannot claim directly from $\mu^* > \mu_i$ to $\hat{\mu^*} > \hat{\mu_i}$; it might be that we just need more trials.

The equations (7), (8) and (9) of the paper is the three conditions mentioned in the paragraph above; left-hand side is small, right-hand side is large or the trials are lacking. Well, in fact, as we stated *the number of runs ... is **asymptotically** logarithmic* at first, the third case can be eliminated(!), assuming that we've run this machine enough.

For the first and second case, since $\hat \mu_i$ is the average of some random variable in $[0, 1]$, we can use Chernoff–Hoeffding bound (or so called in the paper; stated as [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) in Wikipedia). Now, a good choice of $(\epsilon ...)$ will guarantee (from Hoeffding's inequality) that the first two cases will occur *sufficiently scarcely*, or in other words, in the order of $t^{-4}$. To achieve this, we need $c \ge \sqrt 2$.

Now back to the third case, the *enough* number of runs is actually $l = \left \lceil 2 c^2 \ln n / (\mu^* - \mu_i)^2\right \rceil$. Thus, you may choose larger $c$ but receive longer convergence speed in penalty.

Funnily enough, after all the proofs the authors find $c=1/4$ to converge well and actually perform substantially better(!!) than $c=\sqrt{2}$. It seems they could not prove the bound as we did above.

Comment: What do you mean by 'sufficiently scarcely'? And why does it need to be in order of $t^{-4}$?

Comment: @user9947 the t^{-4} comes from there being a t^{2} multiplying factor outside. Together they become t^{-2} which converges fast enough to converge to a constant. The sum of t^{-1} does not converge for instance.

Comment: Sufficiently scarcely is just scarce enough for logarithmic regret expectation to hold.